# Using Java and Snowflake, how do you query using the queryId in a prepared statement?

Tags: java, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use the Snowflake function `TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(queryId))` in a Spring Boot Java application using JdbcTemplate. I would like for this function to work in a prepared statement, but it does not work because the ? does not get replaced with the provided argument. Note: Spring Boot JdbcTemplate is creating a prepared statement from the provided arguments.

The code executing the query:

```
String queryId = "99352ad6-a577-48e5-9b99-07f1f7dd6fc6"; //let's just use this as an example
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(?))";
Integer total = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,
                        new Object[]{queryId},
                        new int[]{Types.VARCHAR},
                        Integer.class);
```

This results in an exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(?))]; SQL compilation error:
argument needs to be a string: '1'; nested exception is net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
argument needs to be a string: '1'
```

How can I get `TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(?))` to work in a prepared statement?

Answer (score 1):

The Snowflake documentation states that the queryId is a UUID. Rather than attempt to make it work as a parameter in a PreparedStatement, I am going to verify that it is a valid UUID, which will ensure that it is not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: thanks for the tip on parsing the string.  I am encountering the exact same issue with Snowflake's .Net Driver.  The query works fine when the id is embedded in the query, but not as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the `queryId` to String:

```java
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(?))";
Integer total = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,
                        new Object[]{queryId.toString()},
                        new int[]{Types.VARCHAR},
                        Integer.class);
```

Comment: queryId is already a string. I tried this anyway and it threw the same exception. I also tried new String[]{queryId} instead of new Object[]{queryId} and it threw the same exception.

Comment: Then can you please include your full code? Nowhere in the question we can know that queryId was a String, so it would help a lot if you provided us a reproducible example

Comment: Thanks for adding more code. Can you add the imports too?